# mix release on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: amazon-ec2, erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, elixir-mix

**Goal**: to be able to run a phoenix, mix release in an ec2 instance (this machine: https://hub.docker.com/_/amazonlinux/)

**Problem**: Running my release produces the following error:

```
/my_app/erts-11.0.3/bin/beam.smp: /lib64/libtinfo.so.6: no version information available (required by /my_app/erts-11.0.3/bin/beam.smp)
2020-09-08 13:17:33.469328
    args: [load_failed,"Failed to load NIF library /my_app/lib/crypto-4.7/priv/lib/crypto: 'libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'","OpenSSL might not    format:     label:  be installed on this system.\n"]
"Unable to load crypto library. Failed with error:~n\"~p, ~s\"~n~s"
{error_logger,error_msg}
```

but I have `openssl` installed in each scenario (`OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017`).

**Setup**:

I create a new phoenix project with:

```sh
yes | mix phx.new my_app --no-webpack --no-ecto --no-dashboard --no-gettext
cd my_app
```

and uncomment the `config :my_app, MyAppWeb.Endpoint, server: true` line in `config/prod.secret.exs` to start the server when running the app.

I create the following `Dockerfile` to build my project:

```
FROM debian:buster

# Install essential build packages
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y wget git locales curl gnupg-agent

# Set locale
RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales && \
    update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8

ENV HOME=/opt/app

WORKDIR /opt/app

# Install erlang and elixir
RUN wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_2.0_all.deb
RUN dpkg -i erlang-solutions_2.0_all.deb
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y esl-erlang
RUN apt-get install -y elixir

# Install hex and rebar
RUN mix do local.hex --force, local.rebar --force

# Install phoenix
RUN mix archive.install hex phx_new 1.5.4 --force

COPY mix.exs mix.lock ./
COPY config config
COPY priv priv
COPY lib lib

RUN mix deps.get

ENV SECRET_KEY_BASE='secretExampleQrzdplBPdbHHhr2bpELjiGVGVqmjvFl2JEXdkyla8l6+b2CCcvs'
ENV MIX_ENV=prod

RUN mix phx.digest
RUN mix compile
RUN mix release

CMD ["_build/prod/rel/my_app/bin/my_app", "start"]
```

and build the image with:

```sh
docker build . -t my_app
```

We can check that everything is running as expected with:

```sh
docker run -p 4000:4000 -i my_app:latest
```

and visiting `localhost:4000`.

I copy the `_build/prod/rel/my_app` directory from the built docker container (as this is all I'll be transferring across to my ec2 instance).

```
# list all containers
docker container ls -a
# locate the container with image tag: my_app:latest. It should look like:
# f9c46df97e55        my_app:latest         "_build/prod/rel/my_…"
# note the container_id, and copy across the build release
docker cp f9c46df97e55:/opt/app/_build/prod/rel/my_app .
```

We create an `instance.Dockerfile` to run the commands of our ec2 instance:

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest

COPY my_app my_app

CMD ["my_app/bin/my_app", "start"]
```

and run it:

```
docker build . -f instance.Dockerfile -t my_app_instance && docker run -p 4000:4000 -i my_app_instance:latest
```

This fails to run, with the error:

```
[load_failed,"Failed to 2020-09-08 13:27:49.980715
    args: load NIF library /my_app/lib/crypto-4.7/priv/lib/crypt    format:     label: 2020-09-08 13:27:49.981847 supervisor_report   o: 'libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'","OpenSSL might not be installed on this system.\n"]
"Unable to load crypto library. Failed with error:~n\"~p, ~s\"~n~s"
{error_logger,error_msg}
```

**Note**:

I am able to replicate the error on a `debian:buster` machine with the above `docker build ... && docker run ...` command, but with this `instance.Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:buster

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y locales

# Set locale
RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales && \
    update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8

COPY my_app my_app

CMD ["my_app/bin/my_app", "start"]
```

and fix the error by changing: `RUN apt-get install -y locales` to `RUN apt-get install -y locales curl`.

I have tried `yum install curl` and `yum install openssl` on the `amazonlinux:latest` machine, but still experience the same error.

**Question**:

Where should I look to make progress on this? It seems to be an erlang/otp requirement issue, but the above is hardly a [sscce](http://sscce.org/), so difficult to raise.

I have struggled with finding what crypto or openssl library the `apt-get` `curl` package installs which causes the error to be fixed.

Any pointers to a particular forum to ask for help, or what to try next would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I see that you build the application with a debian docker image and deploy on Amazon Linux which is based on CentOS. So, try building the app from a CentOS docker image and deploy on Amazon Linux. Another thing to check is to see if openssl is installed in the EC2 instance.

Comment: So it's looking for `libcrypto.so.1.1` but can't find it. Is that file present somewhere in the Amazon Linux docker instance? Perhaps it's just looking for it in the wrong place, or perhaps you need a different version of the openssl package.

Comment: @legoscia I tried openssl11. But yeah, I think you're exactly right about the problem

Comment: @VenkatakumarSrinivasan I tried building it based on CentOS and it all works as expected (with a little tweaking), thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @SamHouston, if your software requires `libcrypto.so.1.1` during run-time, you need to install `openssl11-libs` from EPEL 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion to build it on CentOs from @VenkatakumarSrinivasan,

I managed to get it working on an `amazonlinux` machine with the following `Dockerfile`s.

Building the release:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum clean -y all

RUN echo 'LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"' >> /etc/locale.conf
ENV LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"

RUN yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ glibc-devel make ncurses-devel openssl-devel \
                   autoconf java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel git wget wxBase.x86_64

WORKDIR /opt

RUN wget http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
RUN rpm -Uvh erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y erlang

WORKDIR /opt/elixir

RUN git clone https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir.git /opt/elixir

RUN make clean test

ENV PATH=/opt/elixir/bin:${PATH}

RUN mix do local.hex --force, local.rebar --force
RUN mix archive.install hex phx_new 1.5.4 --force

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY mix.exs mix.lock ./
COPY config config
COPY priv priv
COPY lib lib

RUN mix deps.get

ENV SECRET_KEY_BASE='secretExampleQrzdplBPdbHHhr2bpELjiGVGVqmjvFl2JEXdkyla8l6+b2CCcvs'
ENV MIX_ENV=prod

RUN mix phx.digest
RUN mix compile
RUN mix release

CMD ["_build/prod/rel/my_app/bin/my_app", "start"]
```

Running the release:

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest

RUN yum -y update 

ENV LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
ENV LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"

RUN ln -s /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.{6,5}

COPY my_app my_app

CMD ["my_app/bin/my_app", "start"]
```

I'm not sure if this is a satisfying solution though, I'm open to a more elegant solution.